# How to dynamically assign database table and columns to linq?

Tags: wcf, linq, wcf-data-services

I tried to call linq query from sliverlight application to web service which is 'ADD.NET Entity Data Model' with 'WCF Data Service'.  The linq below is working (e.g.using pre-defined table & field names):

```
        var query = from o in context.ORDER
                    where o.NUMBER == 1
                    select o;

        ((DataServiceQuery<ORDER>)query).BeginExecute(OnQueryComplete, query);
```

But I need dynamically assign different table and fields names to the linq query.  Is there any way?  Do I need to write a method in WCF to execute any sql command?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what are the dynamic fields and tables based on? user input? xml?

Comment: How do you consume the results if different table returns different shape of the result? Can your code handle any class? Is your service static (that is you know all the possible tables/classes up front)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Dynamic Linq samples to provide dynamic field names in where clauses - see: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Further, you can do this in a type-safe way using PredicateBuilder - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

For more dynamic behavior - including dynamic table names - the only Linq option I can think of is to compile some code at runtime within your app using the `CSharpCodeProvider` (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655). However, obviously you need to be careful with security when offering this from a web service.